# How do I store an uploaded image to my other domain using the MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

I've been trying to save simple profile images to my MongoDB database for days now with limited success. It seems to be quite a pain. I can get it to store the image but not retrieve it with a path. I have read that it's a good idea to store your image somewhere else (in my case a registered domain) and only store the url to the image in your database. How do I achieve this using the MEAN stack? Is it even possible?

Otherwise are there any good, potentially free, services that are available?

Example:

```
router.post('/upload/:profile_id', function (req, res) {

//post to a folder on my external domain

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store images or any binary files easily with firebase.

You can set your storage up by:

```
// Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
```

This is an example on how to upload images:

```
// File or Blob, assume the file is called rivers.jpg
var file = ...

// Upload the file to the path 'images/rivers.jpg'
// We can use the 'name' property on the File API to get our file name
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // See below for more detail
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
});
```

and finally.. download the image:

```
// Create a reference to the file we want to download
var imageRef = storageRef.child('images/example.jpg');

// Get the download URL
imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Insert url into an <img> tag to "download"
}).catch(function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/object_not_found':
      // File doesn't exist
      break;

    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;

    ...

    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12922789)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.